# Why doesn't my KVO dependency not work in NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

I would like to use an `NSArrayController` with an `NSTableView` to allow multiple selection but only provided a selected object when a single object is selected (and `nil` when none or multiple are selected).

I've attempted to implement this with a category on `NSArrayController`, as shown here:

```
@implementation NSArrayController (SelectedObject)

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSelectedObject {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"selection"];
}

- (id)selectedObject {
    // Get the actual selected object (or nil) instead of a proxy.
    if (self.selectionIndexes.count == 1) {
        return [self arrangedObjects][self.selectionIndex];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

For some reason, the `selectedObject` method is not called when the selection of the array controller changes (and something else is observing `selectedObject`). Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by creating a subclass of `NSArrayController` and manually observing the `selectionIndexes` key. I'd prefer to do it using a category but this does appear to work.

```
static NSString *const kObservingSelectionIndexesContext = @"ObservingSelectionIndexesContext";

@implementation BetterArrayController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(void *)&kObservingSelectionIndexesContext];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes" context:(void *)&kObservingSelectionIndexesContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == (void *)&kObservingSelectionIndexesContext) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"selectedObject"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"selectedObject"];
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

- (id)selectedObject {
    // Get the actual selected object (or nil) instead of a proxy.
    if (self.selectionIndexes.count == 1) {
        return [self arrangedObjects][self.selectionIndex];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

I used a context (as per [this article](http://ddeville.me/2013/10/nsarraycontroller-and-kvo-dependent-keys/)) to avoid removing any observers the superclass may have in `dealloc` (as cautioned against [here](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Apr/msg00181.html)).

Comment: Adding the self-observation in `-awakeFromNib` doesn't seem fully reliable. Why not in an override of `-initWithContent:`? In `-observeValueForKeyPath:...`, if context is yours, don't call through to super. Make `kObservingSelectionIndexesContext` `NSString* const`. It's not safe/reliable to do `willChange...` after the underlying property has already changed. Use `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior`, and call either `willChange...` or `didChange...` depending on whether `change` contains `NSKeyValueChangeNotificationIsPriorKey`. That's what it's for.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `initWithContent` will always be called? What if it is initialised with `initWithCoder:` instead? Also, it looks like NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior [doesn't work with NSArrayController](https://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2010/Apr/msg00092.html) ([radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/7834918)).

Comment: `-initWithContent:` is the designated initializer of `NSObjectController` from which `NSArrayController` inherits. `NSArrayController` doesn't declare a new designated initializer. All other initializers must route through the designated initializer in a well-behaved class. So, yes, it's guaranteed modulo bugs in `NSArrayController` or `NSObjectController` which, as we've seen, are not out of the question.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of designated initialisers, that's good to know; thanks. Edit: `initWithContent:` doesn't actually get called for me (loading `NSArrayController`s from a XIB file).

Comment: Classic. :( Loading from a NIB should call `-init` for a non-view object. According to the rules, `-init` ***ought*** to call `-initWithContent:` for `NSObjectController` and subclasses, but apparently it breaks the rules for that, too.

Comment: Hmm. Is the NIB configured to "Prefer Coder" in the File inspector? If it is, then the array controller will be initialized with `-initWithCoder:` rather than `-init`.

Comment: Nope; it doesn't seem to make a difference whether the box is ticked or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `selection` property of `NSArrayController` is strange voodoo. I don't know if key-value observing it (and not a path that goes *through* it) produces change notifications when the selection changes. After all, it returns a proxy and there's no reason to believe that the identity of that proxy changes over time.

In any case, your actual `selectedObject` method doesn't actually use `selection` (and it shouldn't). It uses `arrangedObjects` and `selectionIndexes`. So, you should return a set containing *those* keys from `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingSelectedObject`.

Of course, if you're using a view-based table, you need to make sure the table view's `selectionIndexes` binding is bound to the array controller's `selectionIndexes` property, or the array controller just won't know anything about the selection in the table view. (For cell-based table views, you'd typically bind the columns to the array controller and the table view would automatically bind its own bindings based on the columns' bindings.)

Finally, I think you should choose a different name for `selectedObject`. It's too likely that Apple has a private method of that name or will add one in the future.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your reply. I've updated `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingSelectedObject` to return `[@"selectionIndexes", @"selectionIndex", @"arrangedObjects"]` but that hasn't changed anything. The table view's `selectionIndexes` are bound correctly to the `NSArrayController`'s `selectionIndexes`. Thanks for the tip about the name, that's a good point.

Comment: If the observer of your `selectedObject` also observes `selectionIndexes` and `selectionIndex`, does it get notified of those changing?

Comment: Yes, it does. It seems that it's dependencies specified using `keyPathsForValuesAffecting...` that don't work with `NSArrayController`. Creating my own subclass and manually observing the value works.

Comment: Are you sure your `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingSelectedObject` was spelled correctly for your actual method name? It was in your question, but questions don't always reflect the real code. Can you tell if it was even called? In your subclass, is `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` called? Does it work to check for key `selectedObject` there and adding your key paths to whatever super returned? (That still requires a subclass rather than category, but it could be simpler.)

Comment: Yes I am sure. I did try using `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey ` but that didn't work either. It looks like this is due to [a bug that has been around for a while](https://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2010/Apr/msg00088.html).